# graph session empty error in Keras with Tensorflow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i am testing my bigger image recognition model with a subset of it's code which is shown below. Ideally it should be able to load the imagenet model and then display the "hello world"  but it throws up error in line `graph = K.get_session().graph` which is **RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().** i have tried changing the placement of line but it did not work. i want to use `with.graph as default()` as i am using it in my main code. i am using keras 2.09.

```
import dlib
import requests
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)
auth_token = 'WyIxYSDFg467YT.A3MmJlODcyODkzOGQzZjk4YzUiXQ.B5e5SgsDcaMgiRqx21Ydf8M'
top_model_weights_ethnicity = 'ethnicity.071217.23-0.28.hdf5'
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence_ethnicity = '0.59'
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
graph = K.get_session().graph
def get_pretrained_model():
    with graph.as_default():
        pretrained_model = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                                                          input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
        return pretrained_model
with graph.as_default():
    pretrained_model = get_pretrained_model()
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the session graph? With Keras you usually do not need to set it explicitly or call with graph.as_default() etc. However, there was a related [bug report](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8374) that affected your Keras version and seems to have been resolved in later releases, so there is a chance that upgrading Keras would help.

Comment: @KiraMichiru thanks. yes the error was related to version. i shifted to a newer version and it got solved. i used 2.1.3 keras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was due to a deprecated Keras version that i was using for my program. i upgraded it to the latest release i.e. 2.2.4 and it solved the issue for me.

Comment: i have keras 2.2.4 but am getting the below error :

**Error : The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().**

Comment: I am using **keras==2.2.5** and **tensorflow==1.5.0** and am getting the same error as well. **Though I get this error while trying to save a sequential model.**